# TicTacToe: text expansion relative to display expansion? Change listener?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, changelistener

I have created a Java based tic-tac-toe game for a project. The game has a Jframe display with `Jbutton`'s that respond to mouse clicks through an event listener.  The GUI display is expandable by dragging the edges.  However, the text size of the `X`'s & `O`'s stay fixed.  I am trying to find an event or change listener or similar code type that can be tied to my text - expanding and collapsing the text size according to the size of the display as a user expands and collapses the display box.

Here is the code that I have finished to date:

```
package mytictactoe;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class TicTacToeV1 implements ActionListener 
{
    /*Create winning combinations instance variable*/
    private int[][] winCombinations = new int[][] 
   {
            {0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, //horizontal wins
            {0, 3, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, //vertical wins
            {0, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 6}             //diagonal wins
   };//end winCombinations

    //Create the rest of the instance variables
    private String letter = "";
    private JFrame window = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Toe ");
    private JButton buttons[] = new JButton[9];
    private int count = 0;
    private boolean win = false;


  //Create Window Display
    public TicTacToeV1()
    {
    window.setSize(300,300);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

    //MAC OS Specific Translucency Setting
    window.getRootPane().putClientProperty("Window.alpha", new Float(0.95f));


    //Set Window display color
    window.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

    //Center display on screen
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setVisible(true);






    //install buttons in window with a mouse click-event listener
    for(int i=0; i<=8; i++){
        buttons[i] = new JButton();
        window.add(buttons[i]);
        buttons[i].addActionListener(this);

    }// End Window Display creation

    //Make Game Window visible
    window.setVisible(true);
}//End TicTacToeV1 Board and Listener




    //Solicit user input


    /**
     When an object is clicked, perform an action.
     @param a action event object
     */
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) 
    {
        count++;

        //Determine X or O turn
        if(count % 2 == 0)
        {
            letter = "<html><font color = green>O</font></html>";
        }//End O turn 
        else 
        {
            letter = "<html><font color = blue>X</font></html>";
        }//End X turn


        //set font of X & O, when a button has been played, disable button from further use

         Font font = new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD, 50);
         final JButton pressedButton = (JButton)a.getSource();//determine button selected 
         pressedButton.setFont(font);
         pressedButton.setText(letter);

         pressedButton.setEnabled(false);//disable selected buttons from further use  




        pressedButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() //want expansion/drag listener - not action listener
         {//if display box increasing:  && if display box decreasing...  limit box size expand & shrink
             //button & font relative resizing 
             int size = 50;

             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
             {

             pressedButton.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD, ++size));

             }    
         }
         );



        //Determine who won
        for(int i=0; i<=7; i++)
        {
            if( buttons[winCombinations[i][0]].getText().equals(buttons[winCombinations[i][1]].getText()) && 
                buttons[winCombinations[i][1]].getText().equals(buttons[winCombinations[i][2]].getText()) && 
                buttons[winCombinations[i][0]].getText() != "")
            { win = true;}
        }//End For loop for win determination



        //Show a dialog when game is over

        if(win == true)
        {
            if(count % 2 == 0)
            {
            char lineWinner = letter.charAt(letter.indexOf("O"));//necessary for lineWinner, which replaces HTML 'letter' variable
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lineWinner + " wins the game!");//lineWinner was 'letter'
            System.exit(0);
            }//End O winner
            else
            {
            char lineWinner = letter.charAt(letter.indexOf("X"));//necessary for lineWinner, which replaces HTML 'letter' variable
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, lineWinner + " wins the game!");//lineWinner was letter
            System.exit(0); 
            }//End X winner
        }//End Win dialog

        //If game is a draw
            else if(count == 9 && win == false)
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The game was tie!");
            System.exit(0);
            }//End Draw dialog        
    }//End ActionPerformed


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DynamicFont re = new DynamicFont();
        re.setVisible(true);

        TicTacToeV1 starter = new TicTacToeV1();
    }//End main, which calls TicTacToeV1 method
}
```

Comment: I have added the code.  Sorry about that oversight.  I've never posted a question before...

Answer (score 2):

- A guess: you're using null layout and `setBounds(...)` to position your components.
- Solution: don't. Use layout managers and all will be solved. A GridLayout(3, 3) using container would work great to hold your 3 by 3 grid of JButtons and would allow the buttons to re-size in relation to the container.
- If you want to change the text's font size on button resize, consider adding a ComponentListener to the JButton that holds the text and changing the button font's size in the `componentResized(...)` method. You would probably need to play with the FontMetrics class to get this to work.

Comment: I added the code for review.  Sorry about leaving it out.  I'm a bit of a JAVA noob...

Comment: @user2309191: please see the newly added last bullet to my answer above. This is what you should try to use.